# Can I save and use my flutter app permanently on the iPhone?

Tags: ios, flutter

I downloaded the Flutter app on my iPhone and after a few hours I got this message. The app is no longer available. Can I save the Flutter app permanently on the iPhone?

"in iOS 14+, debug mode Flutter apps can only be launched from Flutter tooling, IDE's with Flutter plugins or from Xcode.

Alternatively, build in profile or release modes to enable launching from the home screen."

Answer (score 0):

For this you'll need to have the paid Apple developer program membership otherwise you have to sign your app every 7 days.